# Generate a random number in MS WORD VBA

Tags: vba, random

In MS EXCEL VBA I have for many years used

```
lowerbound=some figure
upperbound=some other figure
m=Int((upperbound-lowerbound+1)*Rnd +lowerbound)
```

I put this in a WORD macro and it did not work; it gave the same number for m every time I ran it.

Comment: That's strange... For me it works as advertised in Word 2003 and Word 2013.

Comment: And in 2010 for me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand it, but if I split the expression for m into smaller expressions and combined the expressions later, then it worked.